# WPF toolkit Change xaml based on build configuration

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, wpftoolkit

what I want to do is to create a different build configuration for .net4 and .net3.5 in the same project. Let's say Release and Release 4.0.

I was able to include nlog.dll version based on configuration, same as others libs using .proj file conditions.

But I have problem with WPF TOOLKIT, because is doesn't have .net4.0 version. I am using datepickers from this toolkit only.

The only idea I have how to do it is to use wpf toolkit on 3.5 build and remove toolkit - use .net4.0 datepicker on Release 4.0 build. But I don't know how to change xaml code based on configuration.

in .cs there is

```
#iF Release

  date = toolkit.Datepicker.selectedDate;

#endif

#if Release 4.0

  date = Datepicker.selectedDate;

#endif
```

is there something simular in xaml?

Mb there is some other solution to this problem?

Thank you

Comment: You might want to create two different DataTemplates and select an appropriate one using DataTemplateSelector

Comment: I thought about it but then i still need to include lib becouse template won't compile without toolkit.dll

Comment: It seems it's a little bit of "hocus pocus" job. You will have a lot of job and maintenance to support these two targets. The simplest way just be to upgrade the solution to .net 4.x. However I assume you cannot do this for some reasons.

Comment: It is said it must run on 3.5 and 4.0. Not like it's my own choice :). To bad .net 4.0 does not include 3.5.